# Read-only column mapped using MyBatis Generator

Tags: firebird, mybatis, firebird2.5, ibator

Firebird database supports read-only columns. Columns that have their values computed, not updated. If I map some table with read-only columns using MyBatis Generator I receive the following error while inserting into or updating the table:

`org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544359. attempted update of read-only column`.

How to treat this kind of column using MyBatis Generator? Is it possible to have insert and update statements ignoring this kind of column?

**Note**:
Using `insertSelective` and `updateSelective` passing the read-only columns values as `null`, instead of using `insert` and `update`, will solve only the cases where I don't want to update other fields to `null`. So, I need another solution.

Comment: I have never used MyBatis, but from a quick google it looks like it has no support for this. Maybe you should ask in the MyBatis google group: http://groups.google.com/group/mybatis-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyBatis does not offer additional support to read-only columns. So, the turnaround solution  is to set the read only columns with the `ignoreColumn` tag and to write the queries that need that column value manually, using @Select annotations in mappers.

```
<table tableName="...">
    ...
    <ignoreColumn column="<read only column>" /> 
    ...
</table>
```